# Azure Function crashes upon missing url query

Tags: azure, crash, azure-functions, http-status-code-500

I have an Azure-Function with the following configuration

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "inputDocument",
      "databaseName": "MeasureInputData",
      "collectionName": "hubs",
      "connectionStringSetting": "measure-cosmosdb_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "in",
      "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.uuid = {hub}"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

As you can see above, I have the `{hub}` in the `sqlQuery` passed as a url parameter.

Doing a request like

```
    https://<my-function-url>?code=<my-function-key>&hub=<my-hub-id>
```

returns the matching hub.

If leaving the value `<my-hub-id>` empty

```
    https://<my-function-url>?code=<my-function-key>&hub=
```

returns an empty object.

The issue is when I don´t provide the `hub` parameter in the URL the function crashes.

```
    https://<my-function-url>?code=<my-function-key>
```

requesting the above returns `http status code 500`

Shouldn't missing query parameters be handled in some way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the sql will be

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.uuid =
```

but not

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.uuid = "" or SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.uuid = null
```

when the parameter "hub" missing.

Azure function cosmos db binding will not handle the missing parameter in query. If you want to handle this error, I think we can create another api or function and put(call) the original function url in this new api/function. Then we can handle this error in the new api/function.

If you hope azure function to add this feature, you can raise your idea to the azure function [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions) page.

Comment: Thanks! I've submitted it [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/39479275-allow-urls-with-missing-query-parameters-required)

Comment: Hi @JoseTomas, can the solution I provided(create another api or function and handle the missing parameter in this new api/function) be a workaround for you ? If it helps your problem, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks~

Answer (score 0):

No, you should handled that. If you check the hello world sample:

```
[FunctionName("HttpTriggerCSharp")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] 
    HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    string name = req.Query["name"];

    string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
    name = name ?? data?.name;

    return name != null
        ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {name}")
        : new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body");
}
```

It tries to read value from query string and from body. In case it's null, it will return

```
new BadRequestObjectResult("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body")
```

so you should do the same, in case there's no hub provided in the querystring, return 400 (bad request)

Comment: Thanks for your response. The exception happens before execution of the task, I tried handling missing query parameters inside the task but the execution never reaches to that point. I think that since I'm querying the documents from CosmoDB through the `sqlQuery` param, it tries to fetch the documents before executing the task, and there is some unhandled exception.